# Performing PromQL queries on prometheus metrics in a text file

Tags: python, prometheus, promql, prometheus-python-client

I have a custom Prometheus exporter that is meant for extreme "hermeticity" - to operate at all times, even when there is not network connection, for a spectrum of reasons.

Normally, I have a main Prometheus instance that scrapes nodes with this exporter, but when network goes out, the team added functionality to the exporter to dump the metrics to a text file periodically, in order to not lose any crucial data.

Now, I have about many hours of metrics from several nodes, in some text files, and I want to be able to query them. I checked to see if the `prometheus_client` package in python had any way to query on that, but the closest thing I found was to parse the text-formatted metrics to gauge/counter objects in python, and if I wished to query on them I would have to implement something my self.

I've searched for available solutions, but the only way to query Prometheus I found was through the API, which needs me to push the metrics into the main Prometheus instance.

I don't have direct access to the main Prometheus instance, thus I can't make a quick script to push metrics into it.

Finally, my question is: How can I perform PromQL queries on Prometheus text-formatted metrics in a text file? Is there an available solution, or do we have to implement something similar ourselves?

Answer (score 0):

I believe simplest course of action for this case - write small exporter, that will take metrics saved to file, and expose them to Prometheus ([using](https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/exposition_formats/#comments-help-text-and-type-information) correct timestamp).

This way you have to make reconfiguration only on one place (Prometheus scrape config) and all metrics are stored in same place.

Note: even simpler it would be to expose such files through node_exporter, but as of yet it's still not supporting timestamps.